# nginx config try_files not transferring all get fields

Tags: linux, nginx, config

I'm fairly new to nginx and after looking through documentation still can't find the solution to this problem. So I've got this:

```
        location ~/project/(\S+)/(\S+)/(\S+) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /project/$1/api.php?p=$2&r=$3;
        }
```

I can obviously get the 2 get fields I've asked for there, but how can I change it so that I can use any additional specified when accessing that URL? Currently, if I write the URL and add ?s=whatever it won't transfer that because of the nginx config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current query string is available as `$args`.

For example:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /project/$1/api.php?p=$2&r=$3&$args;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) for details.

Comment: Thank you, I did get the answer but not that document, so that's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got external help, this worked:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /project/$1/api.php?p=$2&r=$3&$args;
```